# Connection Error when Connection to SQL Server from Node.js

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js

I am trying to retrive data from a local SQL Express server from a node.js app, but I get an error saying:

```
    message: 'Login failed for user \'DIR\\maja.okholm\'.',
    code: 'ELOGIN' },
    name: 'ConnectionError' } 
    { ConnectionError: Connection is closed.
```

I have checked that the local sql server is running and that I have access.

The code in node.js:

```
   router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {

var sql = require("mssql");

// config for your database
var config = {
    user: 'DIR\\maja.okholm',
    password: '******',
    server: 'localhost', //CPX-Q2N4C7MBZ9L\SQLEXPRESS01 localhost (local)\SQLEXPRESS01
    database: 'Retracer Pages' 
};

    // connect to your database
    let connection = sql.connect(config, function (err) {
            if (err) console.log(err);

            // create Request object
            var request = new sql.Request(connection);

            // query to the database and get the records
            let result =  request.query('select * from Configurations', function (err, recordset) {
                if (err) console.log(err)

                // send records as a response
                //console.log(recordset);
                res.send(recordset);    
            });
        });
```

I tried to changed it to async but without luck.
Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Pass your connection string to `sql.request(connection)` I believe.

Comment: @JacobH I guess thats right I will udpate the question, however the error persists unfortunatly